# How to add pip view in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to add pip view for the video , with controls to play pause next , previous is it possible in flutter with support for both android and ios .
*i am using chewie player for playing videos*

**is there any package or it has to be done natively or suggest any example**

https://developer.android.com/static/images/pip.mp4

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/21172855/185163421-f4138ddd-e08c-4563-8bbc-174cd996106f.MP4

Comment: Did you check this package.. https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view

Comment: yes but it does not work when the app is in background .

Comment: I think we need to do via channel methods then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[simple_pip_mode](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_pip_mode)** package. You will have to create a separate widget for pip mode and boom.

[image]

```
SimplePip pip=SimplePip();
PipWidget(
 pipChild: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SpeedMeterCounter(
            orientation: Orientation.portrait,
            pipMode: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      
child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            pip.enterPipMode();
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.picture_in_picture),
        ),
);
```

Comment: thanks ,  but it is only for android , i am looking for both android and ios .

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view

Comment: it does not work in background mode.

Comment: non of them will work in the background themself. You will have to create a background service to keep your app alive.